# Show Post number of specific Category

Tags: posts, categories

I want to show post number of specific category. I want to show it around post navigation

For example

> Post 3 of 13

The code for total # of posts in a category:

```
<?php          
$post_cat = get_the_category( $post->ID );
if($post_cat) {    
    $post_cat_id = $post_cat[0]->term_id;
    $cat_posts   = get_category($post_cat_id);
    $total_posts = $cat_posts->category_count;
}
?>
```

Comment: Don't post code in comments, it is unreadable :-). File an [edit] with your code and add it **directly** to your question

Comment: @steve56 It's not clear what you mean by "around post navigation".

Comment: [link](http://urbanviral.com/to/65136/) 
an example for this

Comment: Do you understand that the link you posted is not browsing through different posts in a/same category but it's paginated post.